# Sprite Kit Scene Switch Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to do a simple scene switch from GameScene to Title scene, but I keep getting the error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)" on the line
                 skView.presentScene(titleScene!, transition: transition)

How do I fix this?

```
import SpriteKit

let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(playButton)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)


        if playButton.containsPoint(location) {
            let titleScene = TitleScene(fileNamed: "TitleScene")
            let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            titleScene?.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(titleScene!, transition: transition)


        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: First, understand how to go about finding and fixing bugs in your code by following a tutorial (like this one: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1). Second, once you've tried everything in the tutorial then you will have a good idea of what is wrong and you can probably fix it yourself. However, for your specific question, I would need more information; for instance have you checked that `titleScene` and `transition` are non-nil (it's a bad idea to force-unwrap a variable; use `if let` instead)

Comment: I am new to swift, how could I use if let? And also what other information do you need in order to understand the problem? I'd be happy to give you more, I just don't know what that would be. @RoboticCat

Comment: No-one can check your code for logic problems as your example relies on other code / content not included. You need to use the debugger and discover what is wrong with your code - probably a `nil` variable but it could be another issue. If you don't know what the `if let ... {}` statement does then you should follow a tutorial - SO is not a good site for teaching you Swift.